# Change page layout for all products

Tags: magento-1.9, product, layout, product-page, page-layouts

I need to change all my products to the page layout "2column left". Now is everything set on 1column. How can I do this in one step for all the products?

Comment: magento version please?

Comment: I'm using 1.9.2.1

Comment: Hi @NielN98  let me know whether you are look for the solution on product view page (or) Category listing page?

Comment: It is for the product view page. All the products need to be this: https://online-ledshop.com/philips-corepro-ledtube-hf-t8-20w-150cm-glass.html . Now is everything like this: https://online-ledshop.com/philips-corepro-ledtube-t8-8w-60cm.html . It are 700 products that need to be change, so I need a solution I can do this in a few steps

Answer (score 0):

You can overwrite Magento_Catalog with layout file named catalog_product_view.xml by custom module and put this layout (2columns-left) in it.

```
 <page layout="2columns-left" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
```

Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

Create a **catalog_product_view.xml** under your theme like below:

> app/design/frontend/Vendor/theme/Magento_Catalog/layout/catalog_product_view.xml

and paste the below content to it:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page layout="2columns-left" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
<body>
</body>
```

You can create **catalog_product_view.xml** under any different module as well.

Comment: Thank you for the reaction. I created this xml file and added the code, but there is no change. I also deleted the cache.

Comment: Check the working theme and try to flush the cache it should work.

Comment: Sorry, but it do not work...